# Duplicating an array from an object and modifying it causes updation of original object

Tags: javascript

Consider the following object

```
values = {
  pieces: [
      {
        width: 15
      }
  ]
}
```

I am storing a copy of pieces in a separate variable

```
pieces = values.pieces.slice();
```

Now i am changing the value in pieces variable as follows

```
pieces[0].width =21
```

But it also updates the values obj
**// values.pieces[0].width now becomes 21**

I want only the pieces variable to get updated. The values object should remain as it is.

That is

pieces should be

```
    [
      {
        "width": 21
      }
    ]
```

values should be

```
values = {
    pieces: [
      {
        width: 15
      }
  ]
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are always references in JS. To fix clone the objects.

```
pieces = values.pieces.map(p => ({...p}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The pieces is an array which you have immutable when you used slice() function. But the inner object is still mutated. To avoid certain situation you can use the below code.

```
pieces = values.pieces.map(function(item){
    //if latest chrome let newItem = {...item};
    //otherwise
    let newItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
    return newItem;
});
```